# Plotly - Hide a point

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a set of scatter points which I want to connect, as shown below. I want to connect the points, but I want to hide the origin while keeping the point (x1, y1). How do I do this?

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, x1], y=[0, y1])
```

Comment: just don't include the 0 in the x and y parameters, but your first point won't be connected to anything anyway, what should it connect to if it is the first

Comment: It should connect to the origin, it's just that point at the origin shouldn't show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the opacity of the markers to a value between 0 and 1; 0 meaning invisible, and 1 meaning totally opaque

```
fig=go.Figure()
data=[0,1,2]
dot_opacity=np.ones(len(data))
dot_opacity[0]=0
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1,3], y=[0, 1,2], marker=dict(opacity=dot_opacity)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mode` parameter to hide markers as follows:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, x1], y=[0, y1], mode="lines")
```

[The API reference of `Scatter`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html) states:

> mode – Determines the drawing mode for this scatter trace. If the provided mode includes “text” then the text elements appear at the coordinates. Otherwise, the text elements appear on hover. If there are less than 20 points and the trace is not stacked then the default is “lines+markers”. Otherwise, “lines”.

Answer (score -1):

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, x1], y=[0, y1], alpha=0)
```

set alpha between 0 to 1
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html